# How to display associated objects from database using rails after a doing filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

firstly i do a filter for my object Folder , after having the result of this filter i get the objects @folders.

i can display all attributes of the table Folder but i don't know how to display otehr information existing in ther table who is associated to the table folder Folder.

this is my model :

Folder model :

`class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 15
  default_scope { order('folders.created_at desc') }
  .....
  has_one :technical_detail, class_name: 'Folders::TechnicalDetail', foreign_key: 'folder_id', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :folder`

DechnicalDetail model :

`class Folders::TechnicalDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :folder, class_name: '::Folder', inverse_of: :technical_detail`

so the related object to Folder is Technical detalis , how to display attribute from technicaldetails table after doing a filter

the colntroller of the filter : `  def search
    params[:search] ||= {}

```
if params[:search][:created_at_start].present? && params[:search][:created_at_end].present?
  @folders = ::Folder.filter(params[:search]).where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:search][:created_at_start], params[:search][:created_at_end]).where(town_id: permitted_towns)
else
  @folders = ::Folder.filter(params[:search]).where(town_id: permitted_towns)
end
```

end`

the filter is working good and i have the object folder as a result, now how can i display technicaldetails information , i display data in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you get @folders it's meaning collection of folders (couple of records) you must select one record of @folders first then you can display attributes for other related tables

here is the sample

```
@first_folder = @folders.first
@first_folder.technical_detail.attribute_name
```

or you can loop it

```
@folders.each do |folder|
  if folder.technical_detail
    folder.technical_detail.attribute_name
  end
end
```

your can check it first before print the attribute, the if statement above if folder.technical_detail meaning it's checking whether technical_detail is nil / not if not then it will continue print the attribute_name, but if it nil it will skip the record

Comment: thank you it's work , but i have a problem when the value of the attribute is nill it can't dispaly , how can i display it even it's empty